# Django ORM strange behavior; model's data retrieves just by '.values()' and not by direct access

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

I faced with strange behavior of django ORM and cannot solve this problem.
Below are interpreter output for some commands.

All fields are filled in correctly in the database and all goes fine with using `.values()`.
Can someone explain to me what's wrong and how to fix it?

```
>>> Models.objects.filter(id=55)[0].id
0
>>> Models.objects.filter(id=55).first().id
0
>>> Models.objects.filter(id=55).values()[0]['id']
55
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found a problem.
I override the model's constructor with

```
def __init__(self, model_id: str, init_ip: str = None, *args, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(*args, model_id=model_id, init_ip=init_ip, **kwargs)
```

and it looks compatible due call to the original constructor inside, but, actually it is not (as I see by the problem).

I think I really have to use something like custom class method 'create' instead.